# Reference for the proof of the existence of solutions to LASSO

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Good evening,

I'm looking for references for the existence of minimizers to the problem:
\begin{equation}
\arg\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\Vert Ax-y\Vert^2+\lambda\Vert Dx\Vert_1,
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a $k\times d$ real matrix, $\lambda\geq0$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and $D$ is a $N\times d$ matrix, $\Vert z\Vert^2=z_1^2+...+z_d^2$ and $\Vert{z}\Vert_1=|z_1|+...+|z_N|$.

I know it shall follow easily by sub gradient arguments, but I can't find any reference to a theorem from which it follows directly.

Comment: Look at the original papers of  R Tibshirani. For example https://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/eelhami/courses/EE290A/LASSO_Tibshirani.pdf

Comment: @Mittens those papers don't have a linear operator in the regularizar - this person is asking about more than just the ordinary LASSO

Comment: Exactly... I need the existence for this result. Which is true, but it seems that everyone is giving it for granted.